# Conservation of Energy (NO PMM's)

Tags: design

A consequence of the law of conservation of energy is that a perpetual motion machine of the first kind cannot exist. My question is this. Why is this concept so hard to understand for many people? I get very tired when someone asks me to explain why their generator can not power a motor, which powers their generator. I want to know why someone builds a giant fish-tank ornament powered by compressed air, and amazingly the perpetual motion machine exists in the minds of many. What is this business all about? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zenn0VD2Bo

Answer (score 1):

First law of Thermodynamics says energy can be converted from one form to another.

Second law says that you never get all of it.

Much like changing from one currency to another, the bank always keeps some, ie the conversion is never 100% efficient  also known as losses.

Comment: @RyanGriffith Do you have a car? Is it 100% efficient% If not, is it now a useless machine?

Comment: @RyanGriffith the purpose of most "fish tank machines" is to aerate the water the fish lives in otherwise it will suffocate. But that tiny question is lost in the rest of the blurb you included in your question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zenn0VD2Bo I don't think I see any fish...What is this for?

Comment: @RyanGriffith my comments here seem to be for missing comments - what happened?

Comment: I didn't phrase the question correctly, it was more of a philosophical one.

Answer (score 1):

Perpetual motion people are generally not engineers or physicists who have a good grasp of what energy is and why you can't create it out of nothing. Neither are they trained in the sort of critical thinking skills that techno-geeks and gearheads must possess. This means they can't detect the flaws in their own reasoning or in that contained in a youtube video of some backyard inventor who thinks he's found the secret to universal free energy.

It's almost always a waste of time to try reasoning with them, because they get personally invested in the idea of perpetual motion, in which case it becomes something like a religion to them.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer. It is as I suspected.